Can't start httpd in container
I'm tring to create and run httpd2.4 image, get error "/usr/local/bin/httpd-foreground: 7: exec: httpd: not found" when run the image,
Dockerfile content:
FROM httpd:2.4
#delete default httpd.conf to use the httpd.conf under local directory.
RUN rm /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
Build command: docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t httpd:test2 .
Run command: docker run --platform linux/amd64 -v /Users/xx/Documents/test/httpd:/usr/local/apache2 -d -p 80:80 httpd:test2
The target is to use custom httpd.conf(/Users/xx/Documents/test/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) of outside container, I'm new to this, can somebody give me some pointers?

Please take a minute to read the formatting help and properly format your question. This will make it easier to read
